# Saving variables between app sessions without an external file

Tags: c++, variables, save, executable

I'm writing an application that let's a user enter text strings. I want to save the strings between sessions of the program. That is I want to be able to close the program and reopen it without losing data.

I would prefer to keep everything self-contained, no external config or data file. Is there a way to encapsulate a data file in the executable? So far I have thought of manipulating the executable's properties or using the NTFS secondary data stream to save the input.

Comment: seems like you want to keep it as simple as possible, the thing is: using a file to store data between sessions **is** the easiest way

Comment: @DimChtz "You can't modify the executable file to save and retrieve data" - sure you *can*. It's just a very bad idea, but it's certainly *doable* with sufficient insight into the file format (COFF on Windows, ELF on most Unix-like systems).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't save the data *somewhere* it will be lost.

You can save data in many ways, but they will all eventually end up as bytes on your disk.

You can use a separate file or database or (on Windows) the registry (sane approaches) or you can do less conventional things like modifying extended attributes for your executable, using multiple file streams or even rewriting the executable itself, but these are all rather fragile approaches and why bother when you can just write a simple file?